# Building a service using GRPC using of java ,can anyone provide me guidance ,

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

when i  try to hit the mentioned endpoint which is mentioned in below proto file , unbale to  connect to service , i am new to grpc using  java.how can we call grpc from rest client program

protoFile::

```
syntax ="proto3";

option java_multiple_files=true;
option java_outer_classname = "GrpcGetRegenaratedClass";
option java_package="com.in10s.GrpcGetRegenaratedService";
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
package GrpcGetRegenaratedStatus;


message PutRequest{
int32 number=1;
string user_name=2;
string pwd=3;
map<string,string> hmparameters= 4;   
  }

message PutResponse{

int32 responseCode=1;
string responseMessage=2;

}
service GrpcGetRegenaratedStatus{

rpc getLogin( PutRequest ) returns (stream PutResponse){

  option (google.api.http) = { get: "/v1/shelves"};
}

}
```

Sample Service Logic::

```
public class GetRegeratedServiceMain extends GrpcGetRegenaratedStatusImplBase {

    @Override
    public void getLogin(PutRequest request, StreamObserver<PutResponse> responseObserver) {
        String str_usrname = "user";
        String pwd = "pwd";
        PutResponse.Builder response = PutResponse.newBuilder();

        response.setResponseCode(0).setResponseMessage("Succesfully Login");
        System.out.println("Succesfully hit the service.");
        responseObserver.onNext(response.build());

        responseObserver.onCompleted();

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: @akortex91 Bro, i have added service logic can u have look now..

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: @akortex91 i am unable to hit the service using endpoint.

Comment: OK, can you share the exception you are getting? Without it it won't be very easy to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: Unable to post complete log :

INFO: Transport failed
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: Unexpected HTTP/1.x request: GET /v1/shelves 
 at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.connectionError(Http2Exception.java:103)

Answer (score 1):

gRPC services don't automatically expose HTTP|REST endpoints (even if you annotate the proto). You will need to use a transcoding proxy that can convert the gRPC methods into HTTP|REST API calls for you.

Commonly these days, Envoy is used for this proxy. See:

https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter

In my experience, this process is... involved and I recommend you read up on it fully and try some of the existing samples before proceeding.

As an alternative to Envoy, there's also [gRPC-Gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) and, one that I have used but is better if you're using Google Cloud Platform, [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/about-grpc)